# C# DES algorithm decrypt

Tags: c#, encryption

This question is about a university project about encryption/decryption algorithms.

The encryption works well, what I need is to do is the Decryption. The goal is to decrypt the ASCII code into a plain text. But in my case it decrypts it in another ASCII code. Here is the Decryption code:

```
public static string BinaryToString(string data) 
{ 
     List byteList = new List();

     for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 8)
     {
        byteList.Add(Convert.ToByte(data.Substring(i, 8), 2));
     }
     return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteList.ToArray());

}

private void BTN_Decrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    lis.Clear();      
    lisToBeDone.Clear(); 
    lb_output.Items.Clear();

    bkey = ""; btext = "";
    if (tb_key.Text.Length <= 1)
        MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid key.");

    else
    {

        skey = tb_key.Text;
        stext = tb_input.Text;
        int strlength = stext.Length;
        if (stext.Length % 2 != 0)
        {

            stext += '/';
            strlength++;
        }
        char[,] twoDarray = new char[strlength / 2, 16];
        int rowcount = 0;

        //converts the key to binary 2 by 2 chars
        foreach (char ch in skey)
        {
            string bit = Convert.ToString(ch, 2);
            if (bit.Length != 
                bit = bit.PadLeft(8, '0');
            bkey += bit;
        }

        lb_output.Items.Add("Key in Binary:" + bkey);
        lb_output.Update();
        //converts the text to binary 2 by 2 chars
       char[] temparray = new char[2];
            for (int i = 0; i < strlength; i++)

                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    temparray[0] = stext.ElementAt(i);
                    temparray[1] = stext.ElementAt(i + 1);
                    foreach (char ch in temparray)
                    {
                        string bit = Convert.ToString(ch, 2);
                        if (bit.Length != 
                            bit = bit.PadLeft(8, '0');
                        btext += bit;
                    }
                        for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
                        {
                            twoDarray[rowcount, y] = btext.ElementAt(y);
                        }
                    btext = "";
                    rowcount++;
                }
            lb_output.Items.Add("Text in binary form: ");
            lb_output.Items.Add(btext);
            lb_output.Update();
            //here we Decrypt our text
            string s;
            int z = rowcount;
            int x = 0;
            lb_output.Items.Add("Decrypted text:");
            for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
            {
                s = "";
                x = 0;
                while(x <=15)
                {
                    s += twoDarray[i, x].ToString();
                    x++;
                }
                lisToBeDone.Add(s);
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < lisToBeDone.Count; k++)
            {
                cipherText = "";
                mydes.Decrypt(bkey, lisToBeDone[k]);
                cipherText = mydes.CipherText;
                lis.Add(cipherText);
            }
            string tmptext = "";
            for (int l = 0; l < lis.Count; l++)
            {
                tmptext +=BinaryToString( lis[l]);
            }

            lb_output.Items.Add(tmptext);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: How do you know that your encryption "works fine" if you are not able to decrypt the result?

Comment: Having looked at your code you might be much better off with using byte arrays to store stuff rather than whatever you are doing with binary (you seem to be storing bytes as a binary string?) and then if you want them in a portable string format base64 encoding seems to be the most common method I've seen. It will mean a lot less code munging your data and less code means less chance for bugs.

Comment: Your encryption is NOT fine!!!  You are converting binary data to string data using ASCII encoding which will lose your data.  You need to convert to and from Base64.

Comment: And to answer your actual question you seem to do all your decrypting in `mydes.Decrypt` without showing us what `mydes` is. My usual mistake is forgetting to set the IV correctly when decrypting which will of course give an incorrect decryption.